# Exceptions that are thrown when we are writing Email application in Android

Tags: android, android-widget

I am writing an android application for sending email which launches the default mail application of android and asks to allow sending mail or not.

I want to know the type of `Exceptions` that are expected to throw in this case.
I have gone through Developer guide and some other Android PDFs ,I am finding only base class `Exception`.

I want to know are there ant other exceptions that will be thrown other that exception, which we need to handle in our program.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Android SDK documentation will tell you, on any method, which checked exceptions are thrown.

If you are concerned about runtime exceptions, those are undocumented. Just use a `try`/`catch` block to catch a general `Exception`, and it will catch the runtime exceptions.